# Group objects in list by multiple fields

Tags: java, dictionary, grouping

I have a simple object like this

```
public class Person {
 private int id;
 private int age;
 private String hobby;

 //getters, setters
}
```

I want to group a list of `Person` by attributes

Output should be like this

```
Person count/Age/Hobby
2/18/Basket
5/20/football
```

With a chart for more understanding

[image: chart]

X axis : hobby repartition
Y axis : count of person distribution

Colors represents age

I managed to group by one attribute using map, but I can't figure how to group by multiples attributes

```
//group only by age . I want to group by hobby too
 personMapGroupped = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Person>>();
 for (Person person : listPerson) {
            String key = person.getAge();
            if (personMapGroupped.get(key) == null) {
                personMapGroupped.put(key, new ArrayList<Person>());
            }
            personMapGroupped.get(key).add(person);
        }
```

Then I retrieve the groupable object like this

```
  for (Map.Entry<String, List<Person>> entry : personMapGroupped .entrySet()) {

            String key = entry.getKey();// group by age
            String value = entry.getValue(); // person count
            // I want to retrieve the group by hobby here too... 
        }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Implement the Comparable interface, then sort the list

Comment: How should the grouping work? Should the persons be grouped by single attributes (i.e. one map per attribute), by combinations of attributes (i.e. a combines map key) or by attribute hierarchy (e.g. first by age, then by hobby)?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much . A combination will be really good ( something like : PersonCount/Age/Hobby because later i will need to fetch them in a for loop. I edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunately your edit doesn't make it clearer. Do you want to get the number of persons by age and then grouped by hobby, e.g. "all 18 year olds, of those all who like playing basketball"? Or would you also like to get all persons by hobby independent of their age?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in Java? This is something that you would probably find a lot easier with a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement methods for comparing people according to the different fields. For instance, if you want to group by age, add this method to `Person`:

```
public static Comparator<Person> getAgeComparator(){
    return new Comparator<Person>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.age-o2.age;
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can simply call: `Arrays.sort(people,Person.getAgeComparator())` or use the following code to sort a `Collection`:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.sort(Person.getAgeComparator());
```

**To sort using more than one `Comparator` simultaneously**, you first define a  `Comparator` for each field (e.g. one for age and one for names). Then you can combine them using a [`ComparatorChain`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html). You would use the `ComparatorChain` as follows:

```
ComparatorChain chain = new ComparatorChain();
chain.addComparator(Person.getNameComparator());
chain.addComparator(Person.getAgeComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply combine the attributes to a key.

```
for (Person person : listPerson) {
    String key = person.getAge() + ";" + person.getHobby();
    if (!personMapGrouped.contains(key)) {
       personMapGrouped.put(key, new ArrayList<Person>());
    }
    personMapGrouped.get(key).add(person);
}
```

The count of entries is easy to determine by using `personMapGrouped.get("18;Football").getSize()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your requirements, but I'd probably use multiple maps (Google Guava's `Multimap` would make that easier btw) and sets, e.g. something like this:

```
//I'm using a HashMultimap since order of persons doesn't seem to be relevant and I want to prevent duplicates   
Multimap<Integer, Person> personsByAge = HashMultimap.create();

//I'm using the hobby name here for simplicity, it's probably better to use some enum or Hobby object
Multimap<String, Person> personsByHobby = HashMultimap.create();

//fill the maps here by looping over the persons and adding them (no need to create the value sets manually
```

Since I use value sets `Person` needs a reasonable implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` which might make use of the `id` field. This also will help in querying.

Building subsets would be quite easy:

```
Set<Person> age18 = personsByAge.get(18);
Set<Person> basketballers = personsByHobby.get( "basketball" );

//making use of Guava again
Set<Person> basketballersAged18 = Sets.intersection( age18, basketballers );
```

Note that I made use of Google Guava here but you can achieve the same with some additional manual code (e.g. using `Map<String, Set<Person>>` and manually creating the value sets as well as using the `Set.retainAll()` method).

Comment: Thanks i didn't know about this Google Guava library , 
it facilitates many things . But i have still difficulties to use it for my case . I updated with a chart which represent the desired output . Please take a look

Comment: @ulquiorra that shouldn't be too hard to accomplish. Just break the data into individual subsets as needed (i.e. hobby and age) and get the size of intersections of those subsets as the data for the bars. After all you'll still need 6 individual values anyways.